# How do I pass a parameter in Report Builder to Firebird database?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, firebird, reportbuilder

I'm looking at doing some report development for one of our Training softwares. I finally got some queries working in FB Maestro, as I'm only familiar with SQL and Oracle.

I have the following query that works and returns results, but when trying to set up a parameter for the display name, the query runs (at least it returns no errors) however the dataset does not return any data. Has anyone worked with these before?

Here's the query:

```
Select CertStatus, DisplayName, Count(CertStatus) From ( With cte as (Select * From (Select COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.CourseTitle, COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.CourseNumber, "MaxTrainedCompletionDate", "Course_ID", PersonnelView.DISPLAYNAME, COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RecertificationValue, COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RECERTIFICATIONUNIT_ID,


CASE
    WHEN COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RECERTIFICATIONUNIT_ID = 3 THEN DATEADD(year, 1*COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RECERTIFICATIONVALUE, MaxTrainingView."MaxTrainedCompletionDate")
    WHEN COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RECERTIFICATIONUNIT_ID = 2 THEN DATEADD(month, 1*COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RECERTIFICATIONVALUE, MaxTrainingView."MaxTrainedCompletionDate")
    WHEN COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RECERTIFICATIONUNIT_ID = 1 THEN DATEADD(week, 1*COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RECERTIFICATIONVALUE, MaxTrainingView."MaxTrainedCompletionDate")
    WHEN COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RECERTIFICATIONUNIT_ID = 0 THEN DATEADD(day, 1*COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.RECERTIFICATIONVALUE, MaxTrainingView."MaxTrainedCompletionDate") END
    AS ExpirationDate    

From MAXTRAININGVIEW

INNER JOIN PERSONNELVIEW ON (MAXTRAININGVIEW."Personnel_ID" = PERSONNELVIEW.PERSONNELID) INNER JOIN COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES ON (MAXTRAININGVIEW."Course_ID" = COURSEVERSIONSWITHAGGREGATES.COURSEID)

WHERE Personnelview.DisplayName = 'Aaron')) Select  CourseTitle, CourseNumber, "MaxTrainedCompletionDate", "Course_ID", DisplayName, RecertificationValue, Recertificationunit_ID, ExpirationDate,

CASE WHEN ExpirationDate > current_date Then 'Active' WHEN ExpirationDate < current_date Then 'Expired' END As CertStatus  from cte) Group By CertStatus, DisplayName
```

This returns values with the static value of 'Aaron' in report builder. But trying to use a parameter, it does not throw an error in report builder, however it just does not return any data.

For example this:

```
WHERE Personnelview.DisplayName = '@DisplayName'))
```

I've got the parameter based off another data set query, and that seems to work (it gives me the option to select employees)

Here is an example of it passing 'Aaron' (with personal info removed)
[image: ReportBuilder]

Example of passing @FName Parameter:

[image: FName Param]

Comment: It is not a parameter - it is a string constant (string literal) because it is in quotes! I do not know the exact convention that Maestro uses for parameters but try `DisplayName = @DisplayName` or maybe `DisplayName = :DisplayName` or maybe `DisplayName = ? `

Comment: `WHERE Personnelview.DisplayName = @DisplayName`

Comment: Voting to close as typo. String literals are simple values, not parameters.

Comment: We do not have confirmation from topic starter whether that was a typo, and if it was - was it in his program or in SO question only. I think closing would be premature yet. Unless TS would abandon the topic never coming back, but again, to early to judge it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the parameter in report, other type database might not recognize query like "where [field] in @parameter", so  I think you could try to use filter to achieve this goal(create a filter in dataset, and create a parameter, then specify it in filter properties).